# PoW and transaction validation

Tags: mining

Does PoW validate transactions too? In other words, would it be possibile to mine wrong transactions (yet I know they are not trasmitted to other peers). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a new block is validated by all nodes. No, it is not possible for a block with invalid transactions to be part of the main chain.

You can mine a block with an invalid transaction. But all the other miners will ignore it.